# Would an MRI of a shoulder cause hot sensation in left chest, left breast has a titanium marker

Tags: medical-science

Just had MRI of my left shoulder, about 3/4's of the way through, left side of my chest became very hot.  My left breast had a titanium marker.  Why was my chest hot and my shoulder was not.  I was told it was from anxiety! I was also told the titanium marker was not a problem

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  MRI can cause extreme heat in ferrous metals, and the other question addresses heat arising from conductive materials, but not specifically Titanium, which I don't believe should be affected